# In Nutch, how can I use my DB to store the list of all the seed URLs?

Tags: nutch

Right now, I am using the `seed.txt` file with a list of domain names to crawl, but is there a way to have this list in the DB, that I setup with Nutch?

Related to this: Is there a limit on how many domains I can list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box Nutch doesn't provide this feature but you can customize [the Injector.java file](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/crawl/Injector.java) to achieve your desired behaviour, perhaps using something like DBInputFormat to read from the database.

In short you can customize the injection step to gather information from whatever datasource you like (SQL, NoSQL, etc.)

Comment: I am using Accumulo with Gora. I imagine DBInputFormat supports Gora.

Comment: Then perhaps using the `org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapred.AccumuloInputFormat` will be a better fit. I haven't played with Accumulo myself but this seems like the right option.